# Are Razor templates rendered asynchronously?

Tags: .net, razor, asp.net-core

I'm trying to understand if a `.cshtml` file that is parsed with the Razor view engine is running async?  That is, if I do some long computation in code, do I need to worry about doing it async?

I'm assuming if the page is already async, there is no benefit to me doing another async on something compute bound if that is all I'm doing.

I've looked in

```
\Mvc-dev\src\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor\RazorPage.cs
```

and it's not obvious to me.

Comment: Well, you can use `await` inside razor templates, so yes it is. In ASP.NET (Core or legacy) you should **NEVER** use `async`/`await` for compute bound work! Only for I/O (filesystem, network, database), which are truly async. But if you want to do "computational" work inside your view, your design is flawed ;)

Comment: Your computation should be happening somewhere else. The controller should grab the results of the computation, shove it into a view model, and pass it to the controller. This is the whole point of the MVC architecture. Don't try to do anything except display the model in a View.

Comment: @Tseng mason  I appreciate the advice on architecture but neither of you are answering my question.  My question (again) is if the RazorViewEngine is launched Async or not.  Pardon for implying that I was going to calculate pie on my page.

Comment: If you look at the IView / IRazorPage interface then the RenderAsync / ExecuteAsync methods that are used to actually generate the bytes that are written to an output stream are returning Tasks. My understanding is that the controller action may be synchronous or asynchronous. But the byte generation from an IActionResult and writing it to the output stream is done asynchronously including the the execution of a specific razor page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Razor pages are executed asynchronously. In the [source for IRazorPage](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor/IRazorPage.cs#L60), you can see the method that's called by the Razor system:

```
Task ExecuteAsync();
```

This means you can use `await` in views if you need to.

Comment: All of Tseng's and mason's comments also apply. There may be some code smells that need attention.